# Encoding in sjplot by using a Rmd-file (knitR)

Tags: r, encoding, r-markdown, knitr, sjplot

I am using the `sj` packages within R Markdown. However, I am encountering encoding problems.

**My problem:**
If you run the following lines, you'll get one cross table with encoding problems and a second cross table, which solves this issue.

```
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)

Var1 <- factor(sample(1:6, 200, replace = T))
Var1 <- factor(Var1,
           levels = c("1","2","3","4","5", "6"),
           labels = c("Zu Hause", 
                      "Am Im Büro", 
                      "In der Schule bzw. an der Universität",
                      "An einem öffentlichen Ort",
                      "Unterwegs",
                      "Außer Haus"))
sjt.xtab(Var1, Var1)
sjt.xtab(Var1, Var1, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

*Pic1: without `encoding=UTF8`*
[image]

*Pic2: with `encoding=UTF8`*
[[image]][

However, if you try to run this in a Rmd-file, the solution with `encoding = "UTF-8"` doesn't work anymore.

````
```{r echo = FALSE}
library(sjPlot)
library(sjmisc)
library(sjlabelled)

Var1 <- factor(sample(1:6, 200, replace = T))
Var1 <- factor(Var1,
           levels = c("1","2","3","4","5", "6"),
           labels = c("Zu Hause", 
                      "Am Im Büro", 
                      "In der Schule bzw. an der Universität",
                      "An einem öffentlichen Ort",
                      "Unterwegs",
                      "Außer Haus"))
sjt.xtab(Var1, Var1)
sjt.xtab(Var1, Var1, encoding = "UTF-8")
```
````

*The output looks like Pic1, but should look like Pic2*

Or

```
      `r sjt.xtab(Var1, Var1, 
       title = "<br/><h1> Ort /h1> <br/>Beschreibung: Bla Bla.",
       wrap.labels = 5555,
       encoding = "UTF-8",
       no.output=TRUE)$knitr`
```

*The output looks like Pic1, but should look like Pic2*

A `rmarkdown::render("File_in.Rmd", output_file = "File_out.html", encoding = "UTF-8")` doesn't help as well.

I think, the problem always occur, when the labels of the second variable (gives the rows) in `sjt.xtab()` got umlauts (ä,ü,ö,ß).

It would be great to hear your solutions!
Julian

Comment: This is working, but it's not very nice....  ``Var1 <- factor(sample(1:6, 200, replace = T))
Var1 <- factor(Var1,
           levels = c("1","2","3","4","5", "6"),
           labels = c("Zu Hause", 
                      "Am Im B&uuml;ro", 
                      "In der Schule bzw. an der Universit&auml;t",
                      "An einem &ouml;ffentlichen",
                      "Unterwegs",
                      "Au&szlig;erHaus"))
sjt.xtab(Var1, Var1)
sjt.xtab(Var1, Var1, encoding = "UTF-8")``

Comment: Maybe I could automatically convert characters like Umlauts in knitr-files, so you don't need to care about encoding. I had this issue before with another locale, but I don't know how to fix this with character encoding like UTF-8 in knitr.

Comment: @Daniel: Do you think the problem roots in the packages by itself and not in the way I use it?

Comment: I think so, but I'm, not sure where the encoding-issue exactly arises, e.g. if it's a knitr-problem or not.